# How to prove $641|2^{32}+1$

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To show that Fermat number $F_{5}$ is divisible by $641$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149655/to-show-that-fermat-number-f-5-is-divisible-by-641)

How to prove that $641$ divides $2^{32}+1$? What the technical way will be for this question? I want to teach it to my students. Any help. :-)

Comment: This has already been asked in [this math.SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/149655/264) (and therefore should be closed as a duplicate).

Comment: @ZevChonoles: I didn't know that. Thank you.

Comment: In a nutshell. Look at the congruences:

$$\eqalign{
  & {2^{16}} \equiv 65536 \equiv 154\bmod 641  \cr 
  & {2^{32}} \equiv {154^2} \equiv  - 1\bmod 641  \cr 
  & {2^{32}} + 1 \equiv 0\bmod 641 \cr} $$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In light of Peter's comment:

we have:

$2^2=4$,

$2^4=16, 2^8=256,$

$2^{16}=256^2=65536=641k_1+154,$

$2^{32}=641k_2+154^2=641k_3+640$

the rest is very easy.