# Is $4\underbrace{999 . . . 9}_{224 ({\rm times})}$ prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is $4\underbrace{999 . . . 9}_{224 ({\rm times})}$ prime?

I wanted to find smallest prime its sum of digits is $2020$. I started with small primes; the smallest three digits prime its sum of digits is 22 is $499$; four digits is $4999$ with sum of digits 31, five digit is $49999$ with sum of 40.For the sum $2020$ we have:

$2020=224\times 9+4$ and desired number can be of the form  $4\underbrace{999 . . . 9}_{224 ({\rm times})}$ . So this number has at least 225 digits. If it is not prime we have to search for numbers with number of digits more than 225 which of course have digits less than 9 and first digit probably less than 4.   I could not check it with my computer. I have these questions:

1- is  $4\underbrace{999 . . . 9}_{224 ({\rm times})}$  primes?

2- are numbers of the form $499 . . . 99$  always primes? If so what is theoretical reason? If not   what is conditions  for it to be prime?

Update: the closed form of these numbers is $N=5\times 10^n-1=5(10^n-1)+ 4$, $n ≥ 2$ if n is even we have:

$10^{2k}-1=(10^k-1)(10^k+1)$

Since $[10^n-1, 5, 4]=1$ N can be a prime, but brute force gives a counter result. If n is odd N can be composite.

Comment: $49$ is not prime

Comment: 49...9?  What about good ol' 7X7 as an answer for 2?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner i think you misunderstood the question (although it's pretty clear).

Comment: To answer question #2, where the number of 9s is arbitrarily large, I don't see why there would be a known answer to that--isn't generating arbitrarily large primes an open question?

Comment: The sequence $a(n)=\text{A067180}$ is available in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A067180) and collects smallest primes whose digit sum is $n$. Sadly, it goes up to $n=175$ only, so such smallest prime for $n=2020$ is not available there (at the moment). 

However, if you instead would satisfy yourself with the smallest prime whose sum of digits *in binary* is equal to $2020$, then the solution would be the prime number $2^{2021}-2^{1359}-1$, having $609$ (decimal) digits, according to sequence $b(n)=\text{A061712}$ which is available in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A061712).

Comment: It's partial factorization is $$4259 \cdot 36418777663409\cdot 851656886812221489761650074771849972581 \cdot C_{169}$$ with a composite $169$-digit factor (not yet factorized), see https://stdkmd.net/nrr/4/49999.htm, and in particular https://stdkmd.net/nrr/c.cgi?q=49999_224.

Comment: One could thought the most of the numbers in this series is composite. For example for $n=7,8,9,10,11,12,13$ we have $7$ consecutives which are composite.

Comment: You can work with such numbers easily using Pari/GP. I tried `px=(5*10^224-1);ispseudoprime(px)` and got the result `0` which means `not` which means : already pseudoprime-test gives compositeness. You can get Pari/GP from University Bordeaux to play a bit with number theory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Answering the implicit question: what is the smallest prime with digit
>   sum $2020$?

$\color{blue}{5}999999999999999999999999$
$9999999999999999999999999$
$999999999\color{blue}{8}999999999999999$
$9999999999999999999999999$
$9999999999999999999999999$
$9999999999999999999999999$
$9999999999999999999999999$
$9999999999999999999999999$
$9999999999999999999999999$ is prime.

Alternative form: $10^{225}-4\cdot10^{224}-10^{165}-1$

This is a single decimal number of $225$ digits written across $9$ lines of $25$ digits each. All digits are $9$ except for the initial $5$ and a single $8$ in the third line, so its digit sum is: $$225\cdot9-5=2020.$$

This is the highest placement of the $8$ that yields a prime number, so this is the smallest prime number with digit sum $2020$.

---

**Edit**: to explain the methodology in response to comments.

$224\cdot9<2020$ so we know that we need at least $225$ digits. We can start from $10^{225}-1$, which is $225$ nines, and we need to reduce the total digit sum by exactly $5$, reducing leading digits in preference to later digits and checking whether each number is prime.

The first number to check is $\color{blue}{4}999999\dots\;$ but we know this is not prime.

Next, check
$\color{blue}{58}99999\dots$
$\color{blue}{5}9\color{blue}{8}9999\dots$
$\color{blue}{5}99\color{blue}{8}999\dots$
$\color{blue}{5}999\color{blue}{8}99\dots$

and so on. Then, if needed, check
$\color{blue}{67}99999\dots$
$\color{blue}{688}9999\dots$
$\color{blue}{68}9\color{blue}{8}999\dots$
$\color{blue}{68}99\color{blue}{8}99\dots$

It turns out that the first prime found is the number given above. The number is equivalent to reducing the digit representing $10^{224}$ by $4$ and the digit representing $10^{165}$ by $1$. This gives us the alternative form of the number.

Comment: @nikgard, great job, how did you find the formula? Did you first find it by brute force and then formulated it?

Comment: How do you know whether $10^{225}-4\cdot10^{224}-10^k-1$ is a prime for $k=165$ and not a prime for $165 < k \leq 224$)?

Comment: @WolfgangKais All of those numbers were checked and found to be composite. I've added an edit to explain the methodology.

Comment: @nickgard Thanks, but that explains the sequence of numbers chosen for testing, which I already understood, I believe, that when these numbers are composite, that someone might have found a divisor already, but how about the case $k=165$? Who proved that the resulting number is a prime (and HOW)?

Comment: @WolfgangKais There are plenty of mathematics packages available that can test primality. It's not necessary to find a divisor. I mostly use Sagemath (which in turn uses PARI/GP prime testing). Other possibilities are Maple, Mathematica, PFGW (which is specifically written for prime testing) and the GMP library for C programming.

Answer (score 6):

A [computer search](https://repl.it/repls/GulliblePlumpComputerscience) finds $4259\mid 5\times10^{224}-1$. I know of no [elegant](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/155727) proof of this, just [brute force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#History).

Comment: could you fix your latex?

Comment: @LuisFelipe I don't see an issue; could you explain what needs fixing.

Comment: for a strange reason,mathjax didnt render the latex for me :O

Comment: @LuisFelipe Ah. That happened to me on another SE page once, so I had to switch from my phone to my laptop to read it.

Comment: Then what is smallest prime its sum of digits is 2020?

Comment: @sirous That question probably can't be easily answered with present day theory.

Comment: @J.G. Powerful enough hardware should be able to preform the search in reasonable time? - Smallest prime whose base $2$ digit sum sums to $2020$ has $609$ (decimal) digits, see OEIS Sequence A061712: https://oeis.org/A061712, which covers all sums up to $3320$. For base $10$ (which is the OPs question), see OEIS Sequence A067180: https://oeis.org/A067180. But sadly the latter goes up to $175$ only. We just need to wait for someone with enough computing resources to extend the base $10$ problem to $2020$, similarly as base $2$ problem was extended beyond $2020$.

Answer (score -1):

is prime
the form $N=5 \times 10^n-1$ is not prime if $n \neq1,7,13,19,25,...,n-1 \neq 6b$

Comment: $n \neq 7n$ doesn’t say what you want.

Comment: if n is multiple of 7 isn't prime

Comment: That is what you meant, but reusing $n$ makes it $n \new 0$

Comment: yes,you are right

Comment: @dantxang:  You can always delete your answer with which you avoid downvote.

Comment: Divisible by 17 when n = 9 + 17b, by 19 if n =16+19b, by 23 if n = 7+23b, or by 29 if n = 10+29b.

Comment: Are you maybe trying to say that $5\cdot10 ^n-1$ is not a prime if $n\equiv 1\pmod6$?

Comment: @gnasher729 No. Divisible by $17$ if $n=9+16b$, by $19$ if $n=16+18b$, by $23$ if $n=7+22b$ or by $29$ if $n=10+28b$. And attention: Divisible by $31$ if $n=5+15b$.

Comment: @Piquito okay you are right that is an mistake

Comment: @WolfgangKais yes, you are right, i try from $n=1,n=7$ then make the wrong conclusion that $n \neq 7b is not prime%